# Trying to import all tasks from list to sheet, but tasks created from inside docs using @task etc are not being retrieved

Tags: import, task

I have an Apps Script running to import items from a specific Task List to my google sheet. Right now almost everything is working correctly. Items that have been created from anywhere other than the actual task list are not being imported. For example, I have tasks that have been created from inside docs using @task which show on my list from google tasks but are not being imported into my sheet.

```
function importTasksToActiveSheetFromTaskListByName() {
  // Get the task list with the desired name.
  const taskList = Tasks.Tasklists.list().items.find(function(taskList) {
    return taskList.title === "My Tasks";
  });

  // If the task list is found, get all of the tasks in the task list and import them to the active sheet.
  if (taskList) {
    const tasks = Tasks.Tasks.list(taskList.id);

    // Get the active sheet.
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

    const blankRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;

    // Write the task names and due dates to the spreadsheet.
    let row = blankRow;
    for (const task of tasks.items) {
      // Check if the task has already been imported.
      const existingTask = sheet.getRange("A:A").createTextFinder(task.title).findNext();
      if (!existingTask) {
        // If the task has not been imported, add it to the spreadsheet.
        sheet.getRange(row, 1).setValue(task.title);
        sheet.getRange(row, 5).setValue(task.due);
        sheet.getRange(row, 10).setValue(task.notes);
        row++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```